# Find the derivative of g(x) = $\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} {{t+\sin t^5}\over1+t^2}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals

$$\int_{\sin x}^{\cos x} {{t+\sin t^5}\over1+t^2}dt$$ I would use formula : $${d\over dx}\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt = f(x)$$ but unfortunately I don't know how to find $sinx$ and $cosx$ in order to get a constant 'a'.

Comment: can you split in two with one bound being fixed ?

Comment: The derivative in regard to x?

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Imagine the anti-derivative is some $F(t)$, then
$$
g(x) = F(\cos x) - F(\sin x),
$$
and you need to find $g'(x)$ given $F'(t)$ is the integrand in question. Just apply the chain rule and simplify.

**UPDATE**

Here is a more detailed explanation
$$
\begin{split}
g'(x) &= F'(\cos x) \frac{d[\cos x]}{dx}-F'(\sin x) \frac{d[\sin x]}{dx} 
         \qquad &\text{by Chain Rule}\\
      &= f(\cos x) (-\sin x)-f(\sin x)\cos x
         \qquad &\text{since } F'(t) = f(t)
\end{split}
$$
Can you now plug in what $f(\cdot)$ is and simplify?

Comment: So basically I have to calculate integral of the given function. When I do it, I shall use cosx and sinx in order to calculate g(x). In the end I get g'(x). Am I right?

Comment: You don't have to calculate the integral of the given function. $g'(x)=f(\cos{(x)})(-\sin{(x)})-f(\sin{(x)})(\cos{(x)})$ where $f(x)$ is the given function.

Comment: @Michael please see the update

Comment: I substituted t with $cosx$ and $sinx$ respectively but I ended up with nothing.